# Get address text from item tag with BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am fine with extracting tag info but trying to locate text is proving tricky.

I want to get the address from this:

```
<item itemprop="streetAddress">Some Road, London SW1 1AA</item>
```

I've tried:

```
address = soup.find("item", "streetAddress").text
print address
```

But I get:

```
    address = soup.find("item", "streetAddress").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Any help with this simple problem much appreciated... I've followed tutorials and they all seem to indicate this should work :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use:

```
address = soup.find('item', {'itemprop': 'streetAddress').text
```

Or you could do:

```
address = soup.find('item', itemprop = 'streetAddress').text
```

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
html = "<item itemprop='streetAddress'>Some Road, London SW1 1AA</item>"
soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('item', {'itemprop':'streetAddress'}).text)
```

Result:

```
Some Road, London SW1 1AA
```